# NetSuite SuiteTalk SOAP Api: Update Certain Fields ONLY on a Record

Tags: java, netsuite, suitetalk

We are hitting a problem with updating a NetSuite Sales Order (specifically we're updating a custom field) but are bouncing off some Read-only fields that we don't even explicitly write to in our code.

We retrieve the order, update the custom field and then call `WriteResponse rc = this.nsPort.update(order);` where `order` is an instance of `SalesOrder` pulled by `internalID` and `nsPort` is an instance of `NetSuitePortType`.  The call to `update()` fails with an exception:

```
java.lang.Exception: You do not have permissions to set a value for element subtotal
due to one of the following reasons: 1) The field is read-only; 2) An associated feature
is disabled; 3) The field is available either when a record is created or updated, but 
not in both cases.
```

Which field is read-only is immaterial here,  it just matters that we're (unintentionally) sending an update back that involves read-only fields.

It strikes me that we'd ideally *only* send an update that writes to *just* the custom field we're interested in.

Is there any way to pull an a record from NetSuite and then update just certain fields?  Or is there a way to inform SuiteTalk to just update certain fields when we call `update()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to update certain fields, only send those fields that you want updated along with the `internalId`.  For example, to update just the memo, and a custom field on a sales order use (in python):

```
sales_order = soap.sales.SalesOrder(
    internalId=12,
    memo='I updated the memo, but I did not shoot the deputy',
    customFieldList=soap.core.CustomFieldList(customField=[
        soap.core.CustomString(scriptId='custbody_memo', value='I also did not shoot the deputy'),
    ])
)
soap.update(sales_order)
```

This will generate an xml that includes only the `internalId`, the `memo`, the custom body memo field.  Netsuite will only update those fields included in the soap message.

Comment: Ha!  You beat me to it.  We had some advice from a NetSuite partner to do just that and it worked.  I was just coming by to answer my own question and saw your reply.